# Do installers run apps with administrative privileges?

Tags: windows, installation, administrator, setup, installer

I run an app installer. It requests administrative privileges.

When installation is over, the installer typically has a checkbox `Run [app name]`, while still being superuser.

When I enable the checkbox and complete the installation wizard, does the app start with administrative privileges?

Is it the same for Windows 7/8/10/etc?

PS Since this is a yes-or-no question, please provide some references for your answer to stand out.

Comment: Unlikely to be a yes-or-no question because there's more than one way of creating installers...

Comment: Can they? Yes. Do they? It depends on how they execute the application. They can easily run the application with either their own (acquired, elevated) rights or with the rights of the current user (unelevated) and it is how they execute the application. A well written installer would run all the administrative functions they need as administrator, and run the application itself as the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, according to my tests.**

To test it I first created a batch file with the following contents:

```
@C:\Windows\SysWOW64\net.exe file
@pause >nul
```

Here `net file` requires Administrative privileges to run and `pause` pauses the execution of batch file.

Then I created a simple installer for it using Inno setup (Desktop shortcut, choose user/machine mode while installation).

- UAC was set to 3 (Secure desktop, Admin approval mode).
- Created a non-admin account.

Then I logged into the the new non-admin account. Now it's time for test. I ran the installer.

First I chosen Per-Machine install which requires admin privileges, completed it (checking the option to run program after installation) and found that the batch file ran without administrative privileges, because Access Denied error occurred.

Then uninstalled the program, and performed a Per-User installation. It also did the same expected thing, Access denied error occured.

**So, that means if you run either per-user or machine install and check the checkbox, it will run the program without administrative priviliges.**